# Find next business day, excluding holidays

Tags: sql, sql-server

All of the columns are in the table, besides the last one. The last column is what I'm after, how do you write code to get it with the current table?

```
DATE    DataQuarter DataMonth   DataWeek    DayTypeInd  DayTypeDesc DayName HolidayName workday Next B day
12/29/2016  2016-Q4 2016-12 2016-53 1   WEEKDAY                 Thursday    NULL    1   12/30/2016
12/30/2016  2016-Q4 2016-12 2016-53 1   WEEKDAY                 Friday      NULL    1   1/3/2017
12/31/2016  2016-Q4 2016-12 2016-53 2   WEEKEND                 Saturday    NULL    0   1/3/2017
1/1/2017    2017-Q1 2017-01 2017-01 2   WEEKEND                 Sunday      NEW YEAR    0   1/3/2017
1/2/2017    2017-Q1 2017-01 2017-01 1   WEEKDAY                 Monday      NULL    0   1/3/2017
1/3/2017    2017-Q1 2017-01 2017-01 1   WEEKDAY                 Tuesday     NULL    1   1/4/2017
1/4/2017    2017-Q1 2017-01 2017-01 1   WEEKDAY                 Wednesday   NULL    1   1/5/2017
```

Comment: self join on date=datepart(d,1,.selfjoined.date)  and workday=1...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to select as long as you have the WorkDay column precalculated.

```
Select [Date], 
    DataQuarter, 
    DataMonth, 
    DataWeek, 
    DayTypeInd, 
    DayTypeDesc, 
    [DayName], 
    HolidayName, 
    WorkDay, 
    (Select Min([Date]) From MyTable T2 where T2.[Date] > T1.[Date] and T2.WorkDay = 1) as [Next B Day] 
From MyTable T1
```